# show the function has exactly one root

Tags: numerical-methods

Given: Function: $f(x)=x^2-2x-3$ $[1,4]$

Question: Show that the function has exactly one root in $(1,4)$

**My Answer**: The function $f(x) = x^2-2x-3$ has one root in [1,4]

$f(1)=1^2-2(1)-3=1-2-3=-4$

$f(4)=4^2-2(4)-3=16-8-3=5$

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(1)<0$, and $f(4)>0$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there must be a value between 1 and 4, say $c$, such that $f(c)=0$. So we have at least one root.

To prove that there is the function has exactly one root in $(1,4)$, Consider the following. Remember that Rolle’s theorem states that if a function is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b) where $f(a)=f(b)$ then there exists c in $(a,b)$ such that $f’(c)=0$

Assume that this function has 2 roots : $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Then there exists c in (a,b) such that $f’(c)=0$. However, $f’(x)=2x-2>0$ is always positive so there exists no c such that f’(c)=0. Therefore, there is exactly one root since there cannot be two or more roots. Hence $f(x) = x^2-2x-3=0$ only has one exactly root.

*Check*: Could anyone verify this work and see if my answer is correct or wrong? If it is  wrong, can you help me to correct it?

Thank You.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work, $x^2-2x-3=(x+1)(x-3)$.  But your argument is correct.

Comment: I meant to say numerical analysis. couldn't tag it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the question's been tagged as "numerical methods" as it is high school algebra, in my opinion. Just write the function as a product of two linear factors:

$$x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)=0\iff x=3\;\;or\;\;x=-1$$

and the solution follows.

Comment: i meant to type numerical analysis. i couldn't tag it right :/

Comment: For me it's practically the same, @Chris: numerical methods/analysis...this is basic algebra.

Comment: i thought so. but is there anything wrong with my solution? cause i think i've got it correct. just wanted to double check

Comment: I really didn't read it, @Chris: it looks like trying to use a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: Lol hahaha okay. thanks